# Issues with select statement in sql loader

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but here is my problem with select expression in a sql loader file.

I have two tables.

**TABLE 1**

```
IDENTITYNUMBER

ID NUMBER
100 8
200 9
```

**TABLE 2**

```
TESTTABLE

NAME ID
John 100
```

**data file for the loader sql**

```
Jim,8
Carol,9
```

Now, I want to load this data in test table by replacing the second number with the id from the first table.

So this is how my test.ctl file looks like

```
load data
append
into table testtable
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
(
NAME,
ID EXPRESSION "(select i.id from identitynumber i where i.number = :ID)"
)
```

But I keep getting this error:
SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable ID in SQL string for column ID

I expect the table 2 to look like this after a successful execution of the loader script.

```
TESTTABLE

    NAME  ID
    John  100 
    Jim   100
    Carol 200
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered loading to a temp table and then running a script to parse and then insert the data with the correct keys?

Comment: Yes, I could do that and it would be really easy. But, I don't want to create a new table in the database.

Comment: I assume that the single double quote after the word "EXPRESSION" is a typographical error or could that be the reason for the error? Also, you could make this scalar query a function.  With respect to functions, invoking a function in a control files is well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think select's are allowed in sqlldr EXPRESSION
Functions are:

```
create function idtestfun(p_num in number) return number
is
  l_num number;
begin
  select id into l_num from identitynumber where "number"= p_num;
  return l_num;
end;
```

and use it sqlldr config:

```
ID "idtestfun(:ID)"
```

Comment: Thank a ton. Function was always a way to go about it. But, I guess I was looking for a shorter way.

Answer (score 4):

Do without "expression"

ID "(select i.id from identitynumber i where i.number = :ID)"